# sniff mobile traffic data

Tags: linux, proxy, automation, sniffing

I'm now preparing an automation testing lab for our mobile department consisting of mainly android devices.

For first phase i need HTTP device sniffing, i can't do it on the device as they are not all rooted and it's not all devices are 4.0 and above so they can use VPN based solutions.

I'm considering a proxy that will be defined in the device wifi "advanced settings" and SHOULD create .txt files with the request response headers + body (since it has no special format and is plain text is should work just fine for me).

HTTPS i'll address at a later time if needed.

My question is which proxy server will be the fastest to setup and script for such an action ?
I guess there will be no more than 10-15 devices that can make a request at one time, load wont be much of an issue in my setup, but making sure each device has his own data printed into files is.

I know squid exists and tinyproxy i know apache got a proxy_mod that might do the trick , not sure if it'll suite my need.
The server machine is linux so no fiddler will come for my aid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two options:

- linux HTTP Proxy with wireshark
- Network capture

It sounds like you'd prefer to use the linux HTTP Proxy method, but I'm including the Network capture info as well.

#### HTTP Proxy Capture

Use [python-proxy](http://code.google.com/p/python-proxy/source/browse/trunk/PythonProxy.py), with the source code modification that I added at the bottom of the page.  By default, python-proxy only listens on localhost.  A small change in their script makes it listen on all ports:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server(host='0.0.0.0')
```

After you save the file in linux, you can execute as an unpriv user with `python PythonProxy.py`  Now configure your android clients to proxy through the IP of the linux server on tcp/8080.

[python-proxy](http://code.google.com/p/python-proxy/source/browse/trunk/PythonProxy.py) doesn't support HTTPS.  There are other python proxy projects like [`mitmproxy`](http://mitmproxy.org/) which do support https, but I haven't had as much success with them (then again, I typically deploy everything in a [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), which doesn't play well with a few python projects).

Another option for proxy-ing SSL traffic on linux, is [CharlesProxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), but I have never used it.  It's a commercial product though...

#### Network Capture

Many managed switches (i.e. Cisco / Juniper / HP / etc) will mirror one ethernet port's traffic to another ethernet port with very simple configuration on the switch.

```
           |               |
           | <--  wifi --> |
+-------+  |               |  +---------+ Eth     +-----------------+
| phone |--+               +--| Wifi AP |---------| Ethernet Switch |
+-------+                     +---------+         +-----------------+

                                                ^^^^^^ Sniff here
```

This method does not support decrypting an https capture.

---

```
### PythonProxy.py

# <PythonProxy.py>
#
#Copyright (c) <2009> <Fábio Domingues - fnds3000 in gmail.com>
#
#Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
#obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
#files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
#restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
#copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
#copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
#Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
#conditions:
#
#The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
#included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
#THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
#EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
#OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
#NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
#HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
#WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
#FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
#OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

"""\
Copyright (c) <2009> <Fábio Domingues - fnds3000 in gmail.com> <MIT Licence>

                  **************************************
                 *** Python Proxy - A Fast HTTP proxy ***
                  **************************************

Neste momento este proxy é um Elie Proxy.

Suporta os métodos HTTP:
 - OPTIONS;
 - GET;
 - HEAD;
 - POST;
 - PUT;
 - DELETE;
 - TRACE;
 - CONENCT.

Suporta:
 - Conexões dos cliente em IPv4 ou IPv6;
 - Conexões ao alvo em IPv4 e IPv6;
 - Conexões todo o tipo de transmissão de dados TCP (CONNECT tunneling),
     p.e. ligações SSL, como é o caso do HTTPS.

A fazer:
 - Verificar se o input vindo do cliente está correcto;
   - Enviar os devidos HTTP erros se não, ou simplesmente quebrar a ligação;
 - Criar um gestor de erros;
 - Criar ficheiro log de erros;
 - Colocar excepções nos sítios onde é previsível a ocorrência de erros,
     p.e.sockets e ficheiros;
 - Rever tudo e melhorar a estrutura do programar e colocar nomes adequados nas
     variáveis e métodos;
 - Comentar o programa decentemente;
 - Doc Strings.

Funcionalidades futuras:
 - Adiconar a funcionalidade de proxy anónimo e transparente;
 - Suportar FTP?.


(!) Atenção o que se segue só tem efeito em conexões não CONNECT, para estas o
 proxy é sempre Elite.

Qual a diferença entre um proxy Elite, Anónimo e Transparente?
 - Um proxy elite é totalmente anónimo, o servidor que o recebe não consegue ter
     conhecimento da existência do proxy e não recebe o endereço IP do cliente;
 - Quando é usado um proxy anónimo o servidor sabe que o cliente está a usar um
     proxy mas não sabe o endereço IP do cliente;
     É enviado o cabeçalho HTTP "Proxy-agent".
 - Um proxy transparente fornece ao servidor o IP do cliente e um informação que
     se está a usar um proxy.
     São enviados os cabeçalhos HTTP "Proxy-agent" e "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR".

"""

import socket, thread, select

__version__ = '0.1.0 Draft 1'
BUFLEN = 8192
VERSION = 'Python Proxy/'+__version__
HTTPVER = 'HTTP/1.1'

class ConnectionHandler:
    def __init__(self, connection, address, timeout):
        self.client = connection
        self.client_buffer = ''
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.method, self.path, self.protocol = self.get_base_header()
        if self.method=='CONNECT':
            self.method_CONNECT()
        elif self.method in ('OPTIONS', 'GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT',
                             'DELETE', 'TRACE'):
            self.method_others()
        self.client.close()
        self.target.close()

    def get_base_header(self):
        while 1:
            self.client_buffer += self.client.recv(BUFLEN)
            end = self.client_buffer.find('\n')
            if end!=-1:
                break
        print '%s'%self.client_buffer[:end]#debug
        data = (self.client_buffer[:end+1]).split()
        self.client_buffer = self.client_buffer[end+1:]
        return data

    def method_CONNECT(self):
        self._connect_target(self.path)
        self.client.send(HTTPVER+' 200 Connection established\n'+
                         'Proxy-agent: %s\n\n'%VERSION)
        self.client_buffer = ''
        self._read_write()        

    def method_others(self):
        self.path = self.path[7:]
        i = self.path.find('/')
        host = self.path[:i]        
        path = self.path[i:]
        self._connect_target(host)
        self.target.send('%s %s %s\n'%(self.method, path, self.protocol)+
                         self.client_buffer)
        self.client_buffer = ''
        self._read_write()

    def _connect_target(self, host):
        i = host.find(':')
        if i!=-1:
            port = int(host[i+1:])
            host = host[:i]
        else:
            port = 80
        (soc_family, _, _, _, address) = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port)[0]
        self.target = socket.socket(soc_family)
        self.target.connect(address)

    def _read_write(self):
        time_out_max = self.timeout/3
        socs = [self.client, self.target]
        count = 0
        while 1:
            count += 1
            (recv, _, error) = select.select(socs, [], socs, 3)
            if error:
                break
            if recv:
                for in_ in recv:
                    data = in_.recv(BUFLEN)
                    if in_ is self.client:
                        out = self.target
                    else:
                        out = self.client
                    if data:
                        out.send(data)
                        count = 0
            if count == time_out_max:
                break

def start_server(host='localhost', port=8080, IPv6=False, timeout=60,
                  handler=ConnectionHandler):
    if IPv6==True:
        soc_type=socket.AF_INET6
    else:
        soc_type=socket.AF_INET
    soc = socket.socket(soc_type)
    soc.bind((host, port))
    print "Serving on %s:%d."%(host, port)#debug
    soc.listen(0)
    while 1:
        thread.start_new_thread(handler, soc.accept()+(timeout,))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: i don't have specialized hardware for the time being, just my linux server, so that's off, started trying squid, but as i said i'm not so fond of the idea since 1. it will not be suitable in the future for https and it's a monster of a proxy, too many options which i don't need but don't know  i don't need :-)

Comment: @codeScriber, in that case just use python-proxy.  I updated my answer with information on that.

Comment: actually working with mitmproxy, also i found out that Paros (java) proxy does the job.